# PHP - How to detect second vowel and trim the word?

Tags: php

How can I detect the second vowel of a given word with php and trim the word by following consonant? I tried with preg_match  function but couldn't find a proper solution.

```
//given word

$string = "engineering";

//output should be

echo "engin";
```

Comment: It is actually too broad.

Comment: show your attempt with `preg_match()`

Comment: Your question would be intresting. please share other examples and complete logic to break any string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i didn't get what you want but i think this might work

```
$yourString = "engineering";

$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");

$occured = 0;
$output = "";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($yourString);$i++)
{
    if(in_array($yourString[$i],$vowels) && ++$occured > 2) break;
    $output .= $yourString[$i];
}

print $output;
```

Comment: Its seems working you should add any live demo : https://eval.in/947584

Comment: really appreciated. thank you.

Comment: @KhalidKhan : bhai question aisa hona chahiye tha ki `Split string by 3rd occurence from an array` aur aap apna ek attempt code show kar dete to ye `-4` ki jagah `+4` hota.

Comment: @user2486 : it involves breaking word after second vowel...although it is not exactly giving what i want but now i got the idea. and ill modify it to my desire results.

Comment: if this the correct then it should be `engi` not `engin` ? by the way good to know that, you got the idea.

Comment: I am glad to help you